# Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year SFSE

Tags: discussion

> Twas Christmas on SFSE, when all through the board,
>
> Every user was posting, and answers being scored.
>
> The tags were added to questions with care,
>
> In hopes that an answer soon would be there.
>
> ---
>
> Each inquest included what solutions they tried,
>
> Whilst people scramble to see what help they can provide.
>
> Though some on Eclypse, and I in Sublime,
>
> Had opened up Salesforce, an app is experiencing downtime.
>
> ---
>
> When out of nowhere I made such a clatter,
>
> I gazed at my laptop to see what was the matter.
>
> Away to the debug logs I clicked like a flash,
>
> Opened the Dev Console, "oh my, what a mishmash!"
>
> ---
>
> I find that test coverage is below 75 percent,
>
> "Surely", I thought, "This must be an accident!".
>
> What's worse is I discover DML not called on Lists,
>
> Queries in loops, unbulkified code, I think you get the gist.
>
> ---
>
> "Alas", I thought, "I must go to Stack Exchange",
>
> "This code is a mess, it must be rearranged!"
>
> Faster than Lightning, I posted a question,
>
> Even shared a screenshot, complete with a caption!
>
> ---
>
> "Now format! Now, comment! Now, edit and upvote!
>
> Shall I add a bounty? It might help to promote!
>
> On, Brian! On, Adrian! On Keith! I've hit a wall,
>
> Now answer away! Answer away! Answer away all!"
>
> ---
>
> And then, I saw in the header, a number in red,
>
> Perhaps someone to the rescue, to relieve me of dread.
>
> As I began reading, and when I reached the bottom,
>
> Answered by Nicholas, someone new to fix the problem.
>
> ---
>
> He was detailed and clear, straight to my point,
>
> As I tried his solution he did not disappoint.
>
> "Just refactor your code like this, here: a link to best practice,
>
> APEX and SOQL don't work that way, but hey, it happens!"
>
> ---
>
> I marked it as answered, and gazed at the sky as I went outside,
>
> "Thank goodness it's fixed" and with relief I sighed,
>
> In the corner of my vision, a man dressed in red, cheerful and merry,
>
> His cheeks were like roses, his nose like a cherry!
>
> ---
>
> "I'm glad I could help, we all get problems with Salesforce,
>
> I'd love to see you at the World Tour, or even Dreamforce",
>
> I still heard a voice as he disappeared out of sight,
>
> "Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year SFSE, and to all a good night!"

I apologise something like this is a bit early. In all seriousness though, I do want to wish everyone at SFSE a Happy Holidays and a great new year and thank everyone for their questions, answers and commitment to this great community.

All the best for 2017!

Feel free to edit and improve! :)

Comment: I disagree with the word "*bit early*"! There is only *1 day, 10 hours, 9 minutes and 16 seconds* left to Christmas and *8 days, 10 hours, 11 minutes and 14 seconds* left in New year. 
All the best for 2017!

Comment: next year's rhyme needs to work in 'seeAllData=true' :-)

Comment: what is the tune?

Comment: @Patlatus It's a bastardisation of the T'was the Night before Christmas a poem by Clement Clarke Moore. :)